# Connect Rails to CockroachDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cockroachdb

[CockroachDB](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach) is a very interesting distributed SQL db, which exposes PostgreSQL wire protocol. So I tried to connect a new Rails project to CockroachDB using the classic pg gem. Unfortunately, a simple `rails db:create` gave:

```
/home/fengye87/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671: warning: Failed to set the default_internal encoding to UTF8: 'ERROR:  unknown variable: "CLIENT_ENCODING"
'
invalid encoding name: unicode
```

So I guess it indicates that CockroachDB doesn't support `CLIENT_ENCODING` variable. The question is: is it possible to bypass setting these variables in pg? Does anyone managed to connect Rails to CockroachDB ever? Thanks!

Comment: An alternative may be to use [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) in place of ActiveRecord with Rails. Don't know if CockroachDB will work with Sequel but it's another path to possibly sooner support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CockroachDB does not currently work with ActiveRecord, but we are looking to support it in the near future. We are tracking issues related to ORM functionality [on GitHub](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+author%3Anvanbenschoten+label%3Aorm-support).

Comment: A few months later.. Now there seems to be official active-record support. See https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/build-a-ruby-app-with-cockroachdb-activerecord.html and https://github.com/cockroachdb/activerecord-cockroachdb-adapter.

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB does support client_encoding but the only value supported right now is "utf8".

Since that's rather straightforward to modify you could either manually change the value used in the pg gem or you could file a CockroachDB issue to the project's GitHub: http://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/

Answer (score 1):

To add to Nathan's answer that CockroachDB does not yet work with ActiveRecord, it's worth mentioning that CockroachDB is currently usable via lower-level clients, such as [Ruby's pg client](https://rubygems.org/gems/pg).

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB is now compatible with Active Record:

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/build-an-app-with-active-record-cockroachdb/